# Geometry . Finding height of trapezoid.

Tags: geometry

Find the height of the  isoceles trapezoid given base AB=24 and DC=6. The diagonals are perpendicular to each other .

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. If you are able to show any attempts or effort into doing this problem, more people are willing to answer your question. You should also format your question using MathJax.

Comment: I don't believe there is a unique answer.  Two cases.  In both start with the long base at the bottom and one side perpendicular to the two bases.  For case one at some height the diagonals will be perpendicular.  For case two, start with the two bases close together and slide the top base sideways keeping the distance between the bases constant.  At some point the diagonals will be perpendicular.  For these cases the heights will be greatly different.

Comment: @herbsteinberg the trapezoid is isosceles.

Answer (score 0):

If O is the intersection of the diagonals then the triangle ABO is isoscel and with a right angle. If you take OM perpendicular on AB than OM=AB/2. The same way you can find ON perpendicular on CD. Sum ON and OM and you will find the height.

Answer (score 0):

Can you finish it with the use of this picture?

[image]